# protobuf-c message over poll() read

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

protobuf-C packs `uint8_t` chars and I am trying to unpack them from a poll `recv()` command.

Is this a compatible format  `recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)` call?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Is there some sample code you can share that illustrates the problem?  I think that you want to use a call like `ParseFromFileDescriptor()` to `recv()` the data.

Comment: Ok well question 1: are uint8_t and char byte compatible?

Comment: Yes, they're very similar types on almost all architectures (`unsigned char` vs `char`).  The only difference in behavior results when you do comparisons.